# Target first child which is not hidden

Tags: css, sass

I have a div with the class `.box-container` which can contain several div of class `.legend-panel`, I want to apply some style only to the first child which is not hidden in the box-container.

I'm new on scss so I arrived to target the first child but not more.

```
.legend-panel:first-child{
    bottom: 2.5em;
}
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: can you please add some html and what do you mean exactly with not hidden?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want with a mixture of nots and sibling selectors.  The following assumes that you are using a hidden class to hide your elements

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}

.legend-panel:not(.hidden):first-child,             /* this styles the first visible if it is the first child */
.legend-panel.hidden + .legend-panel:not(.hidden) { /* this will style thie first show following a hidden panel */
  color:red;
}
.legend-panel:not(.hidden):first-child ~ .legend-panel,  
.legend-panel.hidden + .legend-panel:not(.hidden) ~ .legend-panel {  /* these will reset all following visible back to original */
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="legend-panel hidden">
   hide
  </div>
  <div class="legend-panel hidden">
   hide
  </div>
  <div class="legend-panel">
   show - first
  </div>
  <div class="legend-panel hidden">
   hide
  </div>
  <div class="legend-panel hidden">
   hide
  </div>
  <div class="legend-panel">
   show - not styled
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box-container">
  <div class="legend-panel">
   show - first
  </div>
  <div class="legend-panel hidden">
   hide
  </div>
  <div class="legend-panel hidden">
   hide
  </div>
  <div class="legend-panel hidden">
   hide
  </div>
  <div class="legend-panel">
   show - not styled
  </div>
  <div class="legend-panel hidden">
   hide
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
As @Pete pointed out, the `:first-of-type` pseudo selector only takes into account the type of element (e.g. `div` or `li`), it does not work with classes, so this answer is **wrong**.

<s>You will have to specifically target the first div that is not hidden. I'm going to assume you hide the div's by adding a class `hidden` to them.</s>

Using the `:not` pseudo selector, you can ignore elements, you can use this to ignore all `.legend-panel` elements that have the class `hidden`, then you can use the `:first-of-type` pseudo selector to only select the first of the non-hidden `.legend-panel` elements. That should be all!

This should be a working approach:

```
.box-container{

    .legend-panel{
        // Make all panels blue
        background-color: blue;

        &:not(.hidden){
            &:first-of-type{
                background-color: red; // This should be the one
            }
        }


    }

    // Or in 1 selector
    //.legend-panel:not(.hidden):first-of-type{
    //   background-color: red;
    //}
}
```

Comment: if you apply first of type it will only count for the first element of that type in that container div so this won't work unless the first non hidden element is different from all the preceding elements

Comment: @Pete Oh you're right! I'm gonna edit my post to reflect this.